# Little Snitch uninstalled properly but Little Snitch Helper still here

Tags: firewall, privacy, macos

Long time ago, I uninstalled *Little Snitch* with the built-in uninstaller.

I also ran CleanMyMac and checked all possible leftovers on `Hard Disk: /Library` and inside `Home Folder: /Library` such as :

- /Library/Caches
- /Library/Preferences
- /Library/Application Support
- /Library/LaunchAgents
- /Library/LaunchDaemons
- /Library/PreferencePanes
- /Library/StartupItems

But today I spotted a remaining of *Little Snitch* in `setting > Privacy > Location` : **Little Snitch Helper**.

If I right-click on it and do `open in finder` nothing appear and I'm not able to find it !

How can I get ride of it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Little Snitch Helper is installed in `/Library/Little Snitch/Little Snitch Helper.app`. But I assume that it properly deinstalled, the only thing remaining is the entry you are looking at which was required to give the application access to location data.

I just tried with some other "old" entries, you should be able to remove it by just unticking the entry (if it already is unticked, tick it first and then untick it again).

Comment: I just don't know why I didn't even try that !

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using third party software named [Funter](https://nektony.com/products/funter), which is an absolutely free. You can search “Little Snitch” and remove them manually from the system folders.

If, for any reason, you prefer to search for files manually, here are directories where Little Snitch’s remains may be. All of them are located in the hidden Library folder

- Open the Application Support folder, scroll and find the **Crash Reporter folder**; select “Little Snitch Network Monitor_5EEBD9E0-EECD-54BA-A262-F2ED696E8A90.plist” file and delete it.
- Then, open the **Logs** folder and remove “Little Snitch Installer.log” and “Little Snitch Uninstaller.log” files.
- In the Logs folder find the **DiagnosticReports** subfolder, select and delete the “Little Snitch Network Monitor_2018-03-01-193001_MacBook-Air.crash” file.

As you can see, the remains of Little Snitch can also found in these directories:

- ~/Library/Application Support/…
- ~/Library/Logs
- ~/Library/DiagnosticReports/…

Let’s agree that it’s not convenient to search for and delete every single file manually. So once again, I recommend that you use the Funter app for this task

Comment: It would be rather surprising if other user have the same Crash Reporter files, or Diagnostic Report timestamps :-)

Comment: I already checked those folder as well, but as they are only for log I didn't think that they were relevant for my issue. Thanks for the tip about Funter, I will check it out !

Comment: as I mentioned, I recommend that you use the Funter app for this task

Comment: But you do know that Funter will not help in anything here, right ?

Comment: This is a great answer looking for a different question.